# How to change the color only when I click

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

If my page is blue I have a text "blah blah" written in white and this text is linked to another page, how can I make a small background with white only around the text and the text in blue when I click on it?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qmhcs.png

Comment: post your xml , what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `TextView` with `android:layout_width = "match_parent"` and `android:layout_height = "wrap_content"` and set `tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);` and `tv.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);` when it is clicked.

Comment: Can I make is (Color.#ffffff)?

Comment: Add the color in `color.xml` and set like `textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color));`